# Automatically cache prior to page load

Tags: php, jquery, caching

Is there a way to force my php project to be cached before a browser displays images and loads scripts, stylesheets etc?

Essentially, when a user visits my site, I want all of my assets, stylesheets and scripts to be cached prior to page load, so when a new user either finds the site from a search engine, or enters the address, the load is almost instant.  I'd like to do this with jQuery but I'm open to alternatives.

Appreciate your responses, thanks.

Comment: How would they be cached if they haven't been loaded yet? :/

Comment: Before a browser displays the images? Client side caching is actually done by the browser so all you can do is set proper HTTP caching headers.

Comment: 1) Setup caching with lengthy expiration. 2) Visit your site soon as you launch it (which you probably will a 1000 times anyway) and...drumroll...wait for it...its cached.

Comment: `so when a new user either finds the site from a search engine, or enters the address, the load is almost instant` - what, so you want the website assets in the cache of your user's browser *before* they have ever visited the page?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that, but the best way to reduce asset load times is to use a [Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network):

> A content delivery network or content distribution network (CDN) is a
>   system of computers containing copies of data placed at various nodes
>   of a network.

You load assets onto the CDN, and then it propagates them to servers placed at strategic nodes. When a user finds your site, it can retrieve assets much faster from that strategic node than from a central server.

[Voxel](http://www.voxel.net/voxcast-cdn) is the one I am using, and I like it so far. [I do not work for Voxel, just thought it would be good to reference an actual company]